# Resigned from job but told I cannot work for another employer until two weeks after my official resignation date

Tags: resignation

Hi I have resigned from my job with a company I have worked for for just under 33 years due to stress and work life balance.  My official last day in the office is the 24th March, however I will continue to be paid until the 7th April (holiday pay).

I have been told I cannot start a new job until after the 7th April.  Is that because I am still employed by them and is this legally binding?

If I went against this could this cause legal repercussions?

If I apply and get accepted for a new job with another company before the 7th April?

Comment: Please add a location tag to this question.  I don't know how we can really help as this will depend on local laws and any agreements you have signed with the company.

Comment: So you don't have a job yet? Just tell prospective new employers your start date would be after the 7th April.

Comment: Legal questions are out of scope, but it will depend on the country. If your country or state has a Labor department, I would go to them with this question. In India, you need a relieving letter, in this case, you need to do whatever it takes to get that letter even if it means starting after April 7.

Comment: Some required information is missing.  As others have said location is critical to answering this question.  I'd also suggest your union membership status is also important as union membership can affect conditions under which you are allowed to work.

Comment: A general "*Can I start a new job when my employer paid out my notice period?*" probably would be on-topic (with the other follow-up questions removed) **as long as a country is specified**. That's a general employment question that doesn't rise to legal advice.

Comment: "I have been told..." - who told you this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you were told the truth and you officially have a working contract until 7th April then I guess your company is correct.

However, nothing keeps you from trying to get the next job earlier and negotiating an earlier leaving date with your former company. They pay you. I cannot imagine them saying "no" if you suggest that they should just stop paying you 3 days early because you have another job lined up.

If you don't trust your former company to be truthful and/or competent enough to have told you the truth, you need to see a lawyer specialized in employment law. Make sure this is worth your money though.

If you worked 33 years and left to get a better work-life balance, you should just take the opportunity that 2 weeks of paid-leave grant you. You will get neither famous nor rich if you start your next job on the 5th instead of 8th.

Comment: I like your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no obligation to work at your previous company but you are still on vacation or holiday I see no reason why you couldnt work earlier at your new company. UNLESS there's a rule where you cannot have 2 jobs at the same time.

If I want to have a second job next to my current job, I can. This could be doing a paper round after work cause I enjoy it for example. In my country I can do this without any problems. In fact, having multiple jobs is quite common.

If your previous job says you can't have a different job because the time you work at your new job is during the same working hours. then that's bullshit, at most you "may" be forced to return to your previous company to work due to some emergency (like, you being in IT and a server fails). But even then it would need to say that in your contract that you have to be available outside of working hours. Because vacation is outside of working hours.

Now, the main rule here that COULD prevent you from working elsewhere is the following. Some contracts have a rule where you are not allowed to do the same kind of work in a different company for as long as you are employed at their company. This is a fairly rare rule that companies add to their contract, but it's one of the few that is lawfully binding.

Again, I'm not a lawyer so I don't know for sure. But if you're allowed to have a paper-round after work, then there's nothing really stopping you from doing a different job during your vacation.